# How to recieve and display JSON erroneous response in case of asp.net mvc Ajax in MVC 3.0 App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I am using CustomErrorHandler attribute for handling errors in my asp.net mvc application.  The code is as follows:

```
 public class CustomHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute    // Error handler 
    {
        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled || !filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (new HttpException(null, filterContext.Exception).GetHttpCode() != 500)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (!ExceptionType.IsInstanceOfType(filterContext.Exception))
            {
                return;
            }

            // if the request is AJAX return JSON else view.
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
            {
                filterContext.Result = AjaxError(filterContext.Exception.Message, filterContext);
            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
                var controllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
                var actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
                var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);

                filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
                {
                    ViewName = View,
                    MasterName = Master,
                    ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model),
                    TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
                };
            }

        }
        protected JsonResult AjaxError(string message, ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
                message = "Something went wrong while processing your request. Please refresh the page and try again.";
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
            return new JsonResult { Data = new { ErrorMessage = message }, ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
    }
}
```

It has the capability to catch both the normal errors and Ajax errors.

In case of normal errors, i am building an error model and displaying the error view

But, In case of Ajax errors, i want to show the error message in the form of JSON.

I tried some thing like:

```
function Failed(data) {  // Onfailed call of MVC Ajax form
        alert("Sorry,An error occured while processing your request");
        alert(data.ErrorMessage);
    }
```

But, it is saying undefined for **data.ErrorMessage** instead of showing actual error message.

Please help/suggest on how to handle this.

**Updated2:** *This is how it got solved:*

```
 function Failed(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var Error = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
        alert("Sorry,An error occured while processing your request");
        alert(Error.ErrorMessage);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find strange that you want display some *HTML form* in case of Ajax error. Ajax request uses typically `.fail()` method or `error` callback of [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to get error information. Inside of the callback one can decode the server response using `var error = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);` and then display some error message like `alert(error.ErrorMessage);` or more complex dialog. I suppose that main problem in your current code is because you don't set `filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;` in case of Ajax request in your code.

Small remark to your current code: I think that you can safe use [IsAjaxRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajaxrequestextensions.isajaxrequest%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) extension (in the form `if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {...}`) instead of testing `.Headers["X-Requested-With"]`.

Comment: @Oleg..it is hitting failed function..but i was not able to retrieve error information from it.

Comment: @Avinash: You use `data.ErrorMessage` (see the code which you posted). Instead of that you should use `$.parseJSON(data.responseText).ErrorMessage` (see my answer).

Comment: @Oleg..It was working now. I have totally made two changes. 1) as you said , i was missing filtercontext.ExceptionHandled=true and 2)While creating a new jsonresult , i am missing the content type i.e to set to application\json. After making these two changes, i was able to get error message in the form of an alert.

Comment: @Oleg..please find updated part of my question, how i changed

Comment: @oleg..Yes Oleg..I have made that change too.sorry..i forgot to mention it..totally i made 3 changes..Thanks

Comment: @Avinash: Yes, it's correct. The only remark: one uses low character as the first letter of variable names (especially the names of functions). Even formatting of Stackoverflow use another color for such variables. All code quality tools (like [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/)) will misunderstand you. If you see a function with the name having the first capital letter (like `Date`) it means **constructor** of a class. In the case one should use `new` to define an instance: `var d = new Date();` (not as `var d = Date();`). So please hold the name conversion in all JavaScript programs.

Comment: @ Oleg..I should reformat all my java script code ..i have used all variables wrongly..thanks oleg again for moving me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not forming the return statement properly. In your JsonResult action, try:

```
var returnObj = new { ErrorMessage = message };
return Json(returnObj, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

If this doesn't solve the problem:

- Do a console.log on the AJAX response object in your JavaScript.
- Make sure that you are accessing the correct property name.
- Make sure that JavaScript is recognizing your return as a valid object. If it is still in string form, you may need to do:

  ```
  var returnedObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  ```

**Example**

A console.log of the response from one of my webAPI controllers was producing this:

[image: Json response]

The JSON object is in string form in one of the response properties. I got the object i wanted by doing:

```
var returnedObj = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
```

A console.log of the returnedObj produced:

[image]